# Hide address bar when opened new tab of another application with $window.open() in chrome

Tags: node.js, angular

I have two applications: a business application using Angular and a chat application built with NodeJs.

In an Angular controller, I have written code to open the chat application login screen using...

```
$window.open("http:IPaddress/port/", "_blank","location=0,resizable=yes,top=100,left=20,width=650,height=400")
```

It is opening the new tab but with with an address bar on it. I want to get rid of the address bar. In IE, by default, the address bar is hidden but on Chrome it is visible.

Could anyone suggest a way to open this new tab as popup without `$window.Open()` and hide address bar?

Comment: want to open chat application in new window without Address bar

Comment: location=yes|no|1|0 Whether or not to display the address field. It will work only with Opera. I want to hide address bar for Chrome

Comment: I think that hiding the address bar is no longer possible due to security concerns

Comment: Are you ok with hiding the address bar in the business application too? Or do you just want to hide in the chat?

Comment: I want to hide the address bar in the chat application that I am opening from business application

Answer (score 0):

can't be turned off, security requirement so users know which site they are actually on.
the only exception might be IE11 running on Win7

Answer (score 0):

The Chromium team has indicated that ignoring the value of `location` is [intended behavior](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=537179).

You'll need to work around it. One option would be to put the chat view inside the window/tab that's displaying the business application using a chat library like [converse](https://conversejs.org/).

Comment: Thank you ! but I am not able to open that converse link

Comment: Well, alternatively, you could [visit their repository](https://github.com/jcbrand/converse.js).

Comment: Thank you let me try with this one